# When does the Debugger get disconnected?

Tags: android, android-debug

I just want to ask, when does the debugger get disconnected?

I am debugging my app on the device and when I go to the background and wait some time (around 2 to 5 minutes), my app is being disconnected and I want to handle this case because it makes my app crash when I go back to the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hi guys I know its a little late but for everyone else searching here what you have to do:

Go on your device -> settings -> developer options -> select debug app -> turn on 'Wait for debugger'

[image]

Now on Android Studio run the app in debug mode, close it and wait for the process to close (causing it to detach from the debugger) and reopen it from the **recent** drawer. You will get a waiting for debugger message on the device.

Go on Android Studio and press the attach debugger to process button [image], select the process and done :D

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. In my case, the debugger was getting disconnected every time the system destroyed the app after being stopped for a while (i.e. in the background). This happens when the system needs more memory/resources for the foreground app or when your app has been stopped for too long, cf. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html.

The best way I have found to debug this is to add Log.d() logging ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String, java.lang.String](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). After I started logging all lifecycle events, I found that in my case the following was happening:

- *I switch to a different foreground app, causing my app to go in the background in a stopped state*
- onPause()
- onStop()
- *debugger disconnects (typically after a few minutes, sooner if using a memory intensive foreground app). Note that onDestroy() doesn't get called here but activity does get destroyed.*
- *I re-launch my app, debugger is no longer attached*
- onCreate() - system tries to re-create activity using savedInstanceState
- onStart()
- onResume()

Because the system was the one that destroyed the activity, when it re-creates the activity it tries to restore the state of all Views. If you need to save additional information, be sure to override the onSaveInstanceState() method which gets called before the activity is destroyed, and then recover the saved information by accessing the savedInstanceState Bundle in the Activity's onCreate() method.

Hope that helps.